# Unable to set ANDROID_HOME environment variable Android SDK + phonegap

Tags: cordova, android-studio, path, sdk, ubuntu-16.04

I'm on step 7 in the this tutorial

[phonegap in ubuntu tutorial link](http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/)

When i type 'android' into terminal android sdk program loads

[sdk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoPiL.png)

but when i run

```
sudo phonegap run android
```

after successfully running

```
phonegap create testapp
phonegap platform add android
phonegap platform -ls
```

i get this error

> phonegap] executing 'cordova run android ' ... Error: Failed to find
>   'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your
>   'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory

ive set my ~/bashrc like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/david/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:/home/david/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/david/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/david/Android/Sdk/build-tools
```

and my ~/.profile like this

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_TOOLS="$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

and there are no other .profile* files in my home directory

I had hoped on working on this project in ubuntu but if i can't figure this out soon i'll have to use my windows partition :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue with this was that i had downloaded Android SDK studio instead of the command line version or something.